# /security/alerts not returning from Azure Identity Protection (IPC)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-security

All our customers now return no data for Azure Identity Protection  (IPC). This started wednesday 12th jun. Before that we had alerts on all our customers. Rechecked many tenants against their Azure AD Identity Protection and they DO have recent alerts. Not returned by graph api

Answer (score 1):

We investigated and deployed a fix for this last week. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: What was the fix? Any documentation accompanying it?